# Is secure launch a thread without join?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

In a web app i have a method, this waits for another thread for generate reports if the quantity of customers is less than 10, but if greater than 10 i start my thread but without apply the join method, when the thread finish i notify by e-mail.

I'm a little afraid about the orphan threads with a large execution and the impact on the server.

Is good launch a "heavy" process in background (asynchronically) without use the join method or there is a better way to make it?

```
try {
        thread.start();
        if(flagSendEmail > 10){                     
            return "{\"message\":\"success\", \"text\":\"you will be notified by email\"}";
        }else{
              thread.join();            //the customer waits until finish           
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             LogError.saveErrorApp(e.getMessage(), e);
             return "{\"message\":\"danger\", \"text\":\"can't generate the reports\"}";
    }
```

Comment: What is your alternative? Not joining on the thread causes what to happen in your application? I can tell you that you aren't supposed to start *any* threads in a Java web application.

Comment: without the join method, i get an orphan thread, the app works fine, but i am not sure if a good implementation or benefits of another implementation, i want to improve it

Comment: You should use an ExecutorService instead. This allows making sure not too many threads run concurrently, and it allows keeping a reference to the executor, allowing to shut it down when the application must stop.

Comment: Where is the `return` after the `thread.join()` call?

Comment: yes, i forget it, after the catch. And the thread is instanciate before the try

Answer (score 2):

Orphan threads aren't the problem, simply make sure that the `run()` method has a finally block that sends out the email.

The problem is that you have no control over the number of threads and that's got nothing to do with calling `join()`. (Unless you always wait for every single thread in the caller, at which point there's no point launching a background thread in the first place.)

The solution is to use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which gives you a **thread pool**, and thus precise control over how many of these background threads are running at any one time. If you submit more tasks than the executor can handle at a given time, the remaining ones are queued up, waiting to be run. This way you can control the load on your server.

An added bonus is that because an executor service will typically recycle the same worker threads, the overhead of submitting a new task is less, meaning that you don't need to bother about whether you've got more than 10 items or not, everything can be run the same way.

In your case you could even consider using two separate executors: one for running the report generation and another one for sending out the emails. The reason for this is that you may want to limit the number of emails sent out in a busy period but without slowing report generation down.

Comment: ExecutorService sounds good, better with Callables instead implements runnable?

Comment: `Callable`s are useful if you want to return a value. But in a truly asynchronous process you never do that, you just use callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point is starting a thread if the very next thing you do is `join()` it.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if your example is on the right path, then this would be even better because it avoids creating and destroying a new thread (expensive) in the `flagSendEmail <= 10` case:

```
Runnable r = ...;

if (flagSendEmail > 10) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
    return "...";
} else {
    r.run();
    return ???
}
```

---

But chances are, you should not be explicitly creating new Threads at all.  Any time a program *continually* creates and destroys threads, that's a sign that it should be using a *thread pool* instead.  (See the javadoc for `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`)

---

By the way:  `t.join()` does not do anything to thread `t`.  It doesn't do anything at all except wait until thread `t` is dead.

Comment: Not contradicting your last paragraph but `join()` does something more subtle too: it establishes a formal happens-before relationship with `t`'s death.

Comment: @biziclop, Yes, Guilty as charged.  I do it more often when I'm responding to some noob who thinks that `synchronized(foo)...` will prevent other threads from accessing the `foo` object.  I say, "The only thing `synchronized(foo)` does is ...", and then I leave out any mention of memory model or "happens before".  I guess I should find some new way to say it that is simple enough for a noob, but not technically untrue.

Comment: I didn't mean it as criticism, more as a signpost for anyone who may stumble into this answer in the future.

Comment: mm thanks, definitely i must consider the ThreadPoolExecutor or  ExecutorService options, i'll read about that

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe, I don't recall seeing any `Thread#join()` actual invocations.

But it will depends on what are you trying to do. I don't know if you mean to use a pool or threads that generate reports or have some resource assigned. In any case you should limit yourself to a maximum number of threads for reports. If they are getting blocked or looped (for some bug or poor synchronization), allowing more and more threads will utterly clog your application.

`Thread#join` waits for the referred thread to die. Are those threads actually ending? Are you waiting for a thread to die just to launch another thread? Usually synchronization is done with `wait()` and `notify()` over the synchronization object.

Launching a process (`Runtime#exec()`) probably will make things even worse, unless it helps work around some weird limitation.

There are some tools like [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) which can give you some heads up about threads getting locked and other issues.

Comment: yes, the threads ending, mmm but sometimes they are slow to finish due to save in external storage service. I just launch one thread when the request comes from client. But you had say something important, about launch another thread, i must check it

Comment: @user3002695 so if they take time because writing into disk, that might be the actual bottleneck and more threads competing for a busy resource will make things worse.

You might also try to optimize the I/O for that case. For example check that some buffering is used: A `BufferedOutputStream`(tip: use the file block size) between `PrintStream` -> `FileOutputStream` can make the char by char writing operation look like a slug.